# InfluxDB empty result set

Tags: java, docker, influxdb

I run influxdb in docker with default settings (docker run -p 8086:8086 influxdb:1.7.4) and i try to insert some data using influx java driver (2.15):

```
public class BasicUsageTest {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BasicUsageTest.class);

    public static InfluxDB influxdb;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {
        logger.info("Connect to influxdb");
        influxdb = InfluxDBFactory.connect("http://localhost:8086");
//        influxdb.query(new Query("create database test"));
//        influxdb.query(new Query("create retention policy rp on test duration 1h replication 1"));
        influxdb.setLogLevel(InfluxDB.LogLevel.FULL);
        influxdb.setConsistency(InfluxDB.ConsistencyLevel.ALL);
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll() {
        influxdb.close();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void truncate() {
//        influxdb.query(new Query("drop series from metric"));
    }

    @Test
    public void select() {
        Point point = Point.measurement("metric")
                .addField("c1", 1)
                .addField("c2", 2)
                .addField("c3", 3)
                .build();

        influxdb.write("test", "rp", point);

        logger.info("Select query");
        QueryResult result = influxdb.query(new Query("select * from metric", "test"));

        logger.info(result);
    }
}
```

The problem is that query always returns `INFO: {"results":[{"statement_id":0}]}`.
I also tried to connect to influx shell (`docker exec -it influxdb influx`) and select some data manually (`select * from metric`) but i also get empty result. In the meantime, if i insert some data using shell (`insert metric, c1=1 c2=2,c3=3`) i'll get this row (but column c1 encoded as string and i don't know why).

Influxdb logs:

> Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:
>   --> POST http://localhost:8086/write?db=test&rp=rp&precision=n&consistency=all
>   Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Content-Length: 25 Mar
>   25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:  Mar
>   25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:
>   metric c1=1i,c2=2i,c3=3i
>
> Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:
>   --> END POST (25-byte body) Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: <-- 204 No Content
>   http://localhost:8086/write?db=test&rp=rp&precision=n&consistency=all
>   (56ms) Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
>   INFO: Content-Type: application/json Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Request-Id:
>   5e792a10-4f3e-11e9-805e-0242ac110002 Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: X-Influxdb-Build: OSS Mar
>   25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:
>   X-Influxdb-Version: 1.7.4 Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: X-Request-Id:
>   5e792a10-4f3e-11e9-805e-0242ac110002 Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2019
>   20:41:30 GMT Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: <-- END HTTP
>
> Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:
>   --> GET http://localhost:8086/query?db=test&q=select+*+from+metric Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: -->
>   END GET Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform
>   log INFO: <-- 200 OK
>   http://localhost:8086/query?db=test&q=select+*+from+metric (5ms) Mar
>   25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:
>   Content-Type: application/json Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Request-Id:
>   5e7df49c-4f3e-11e9-805f-0242ac110002 Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: X-Influxdb-Build: OSS Mar
>   25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:
>   X-Influxdb-Version: 1.7.4 Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: X-Request-Id:
>   5e7df49c-4f3e-11e9-805f-0242ac110002 Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2019
>   20:41:30 GMT Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM
>   okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform
>   log INFO:  Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform
>   log INFO: {"results":[{"statement_id":0}]}
>
> Mar 25, 2019 11:41:27 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO:
>   <-- END HTTP (33-byte body)

Comment: Seems like you write datapoint into on-default retention policy "rp" while do select from a default one. Try to specify a fully qualified measurement in select: FROM <database_name>.<retention_policy_name>.<measurement_name>

Comment: @YuriLachin, thank you! It finally worked. 
But it's very strange, because i thought that i tried once the same. Anyway, thank you again :)